# how to message another agent at remote host using jade?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I am a novice to JADE .
I want to message an agent on remote host from another agent,but other than starting an agent platform from cmd i cannot figure out anything. 
Hope to get this issue resolved.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the 'Java Code' for this problem?

Comment: yep i am also trying to figure this out

Comment: you can do accessing cmd using java by new Runtime().exec(). or you may also use processBuilder,  which is the better technique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry community for wasting your time here i have figured it out myself:-

```
    ACLMessage msgp = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.SUBSCRIBE);
    msgp.setContent("subscribe1");
    AID remoteAMSf = new AID("salubhai@192.168.2.9:12349/JADE", AID.ISGUID);
    remoteAMSf.addAddresses("http://192.168.2.9:64505/acc");
    msgp.addReceiver(remoteAMSf);
    send(msgp);
```